# How many ways can you add the numbers 1, 2, and 3 to create a number n?

Tags: permutations, integer-partitions, pattern-recognition

I would like to find an equation in which, given a number n, you can find the amount of ways to add 1, 2, and 3 to create the number. The commutative rule doesn't apply; for example, 1 + 1 + 3 is a different arrangement than 1 + 3 + 1.
Let's take the number 4 for an example. There are 7 ways to combine the numbers 1, 2, and 3 to create 4:
1 1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
2 1 1
1 3
3 1
2 2

Any ideas?

Comment: Tribonacci numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of such partitions.  Then $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2, a_3 = 4$, and by conditioning on the size of the first part, we find that
$$a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}.$$
Do you know how to solve this recurrence relation?